Why am I getting Compilation Error from web.config
We have a .NET 4.8 WCF project that was working just fine and compiles just fine but is now throwing up the following web.config compilation error when I try to access any end point:

Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OurCompany' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:
    
    Line 64:     </compilation>
    Line 65:     <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="false" requireSSL="false" domain="" />
    Line 66:     <profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="IBProfileProvider" automaticSaveEnabled="false" inherits="OurCompany.Internet.Infrastructure.IB.UserState.WebUserProfile">
    Line 67:       <providers>
    Line 68:         <clear />
    
    Source File: c:\Web.config    Line: 66

The offending lines in the web.config are:
<profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="IBProfileProvider" 
         automaticSaveEnabled="false"  
         inherits="OurCompany.Internet.Infrastructure.IB.UserState.WebUserProfile">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="IBProfileProvider" 
             type="OurCompany.Imported.Microsoft.Profile.SqlProfileProvider,Infrastructure.Internet.CustomProviders, version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" 
             connectionStringName="AspNetConnectionString" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
    <properties />
</profile>

I have cleaned and rebuilt every project, manually removed bin and obj from every project and even reloaded each project but to no avail.
Even when I comment out the offending lines in the web.config, I still get this error.

Is the root namespace of your assembly and classes within your project "OurCompany"?  Is it possible that someone renamed the namespace or there was some kind of mangling from a global search & replace? Look at the source control history for the web.config and this "OurCompany.Imported.Microsoft.Profile.SqlProfileProvider,Infrastructure.Internet.CustomProviders" class.

I would look at source control for changes and then also, if you use VS2022, sometimes it goes crazy, not recognizing references and namespaces. Close all instances and try again.

I have restarted VS several times, rebooted my machine several times but to no avail. I have also cloned fresh from repo. The code compiles perfectly its just when running i get this error. Last edit to web.config was 7th May. And no-one else in my team is having this issues so I wonder if it is machine specific

What I don't understand is why I get this same error even when I comment out the offending lines in the web.config

Do you have something in your </compilation> tag? Are you pre-compiling something? Well, yea. If no one else has it than something on your side. Try to clean the internet cache as well.

Compilation tag:






Ok found the problem. We recently moved our repo from azure to github and my local iis was referencing the old repo folder hence the errors. It also explains why commenting out the web.config didn't work. Once I set the iis settings to the correct one it is working fine. Thanks for all your help
